# SQL Raw to mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need to execute the following query:

```
select Clients.Zip, AVG(SpentT) as Average_Spent_Per_Zipcode 
from  
    (select CLIENT.CLIENT_ID AS ClientID, Averages.Spent AS SpentT, CLIENT.ZIPCODE AS Zip  
     from CLIENT,  
        (select CLIENT_ID, AVG(MENU.PRICE) AS Spent 
        from ORDER_HISTORY, MENU 
        where (ORDER_HISTORY.FOOD = MENU.FOOD) 
        AND (ORDER_HISTORY.RESTAURANT_ID = MENU.RESTAURANT_ID)  
        group by ORDER_HISTORY.CLIENT_ID)  
         AS Averages  
     where CLIENT.CLIENT_ID = Averages.CLIENT_ID) AS Clients  
group by Clients.Zip 
order by Average_Spent_Per_Zipcode DESC
```

I know this probably isn't the most straightforward query but the idea is to find the zipcodes that spend the most at a restaurant on average.

I've tried

```
sqlP1=text('select Clients.Zip, AVG(SpentT) as Average_Spent_Per_Zipcode from (select  CLIENT.CLIENT_ID AS ClientID, Averages.Spent AS SpentT, CLIENT.ZIPCODE AS Zip from CLIENT, (select CLIENT_ID, AVG(MENU.PRICE) AS Spent from ORDER_HISTORY, MENU where (ORDER_HISTORY.FOOD = MENU.FOOD) AND (ORDER_HISTORY.RESTAURANT_ID = MENU.RESTAURANT_ID) group by ORDER_HISTORY.CLIENT_ID) AS Averages where CLIENT.CLIENT_ID = Averages.CLIENT_ID) AS Clients group by Clients.Zip order by Average_Spent_Per_Zipcode DESC')
result= db.engine.execute(sql)
```

but i keep getting any error and i am new to this so i am not sure if logs would help/where id find them.
If someone knows how to perform this query it would be awesome! 
Your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you post the error please

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application. @Adrian I don't know how to check the logs for a more precise error. Are there possibly some imports i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.ZIPCODE, AVG(M.PRICE) AS Average_Spent_Per_Zipcode  
FROM ORDER_HISTORY OH 
INNER JOIN MENU M ON OH.FOOD = M.FOOD AND OH.RESTAURANT_ID = M.RESTAURANT_ID 
INNER JOIN CLIENT C ON OH.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID 
GROUP BY C.ZIPCODE 
ORDER BY AVG(M.PRICE) DESC;
```

Comment: Do you know how i find if im missing an import statement? @Saharsh Shah